# GUI editor for polkit?

Tags: policykit

Searching for GUI and polkit (with or without "editor") only give me lots of links to authentication agents. But on my travels I found a [screenshot showing just what I was looking](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=978579&p=6151280#post6151280) for:

[image: window with the title Authorizations showing a tree-view on the left side in which polkit authorizations may be selected and controls on the right to adjust them]

What is this program?

Comment: As far as I could search, It was with 08.04 then dropped later.

Comment: There is also similar tool in AstraLinux but failed to find where source code is published (RU site).  https://download.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/orel/repository/pool/main/f/fly-admin-policykit-1/

Comment: Not sure this is the same program, but here is another link (I didn't check it out as it requires registering on the actual site): https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/syndicated-linux-news-67/lxer-those-polkit-policykit-xml-files-a-pain-to-view-polkit-explorer-now-avaiable-4175456294/ ...it is called "Polkit Explorer" in the linked forum post

Comment: @user.dz Astra Linux is proprietary software, presumably spyware. Don't use it.